# Auto login after changing domains

Tags: powershell

I have computers that are not on a domain that need to be added to a domain, restarted, auto login with a domain account and then have a few powershell scripts run on them.

I have a powershell that edits the registry with domain credentials and sets it to login once with a runonce command for a script. When I run the powershell it edits the registry correctly, changes to the correct domain and then restarts the computer after a 10 second wait. When the computer comes back online and tries to login it gives a "There are currently no logon servers available to process your logon request" if you then type in the domain password for the account it lets you login and then runs the runonce script. I would like to not have to type in a password manually.

Here is the powershell code I am currently using. I am using powershell v1 because all the computers will have that on them and they are windows 7 machines.

```
Function Set-AutoLogon{

    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [String[]]$DefaultUsername,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [String[]]$DefaultDomainName,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [String[]]$DefaultPassword,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [AllowEmptyString()]
        [String[]]$AutoLogonCount,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [AllowEmptyString()]
        [String[]]$Script

    )

    Begin
    {
        #Registry path declaration
        $RegPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon"
        $RegROPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce"

    }

    Process
    {

        try
        {
            #setting registry values
            Set-ItemProperty $RegPath "AutoAdminLogon" -Value "1" -type String  
            Set-ItemProperty $RegPath "DefaultUsername" -Value "$DefaultUsername" -type String
            Set-ItemProperty $RegPath "DefaultDomainName" -Value "$DefaultDomainName" -type String  
            Set-ItemProperty $RegPath "DefaultPassword" -Value "$DefaultPassword" -type String
            if($AutoLogonCount)
            {

                Set-ItemProperty $RegPath "AutoLogonCount" -Value "$AutoLogonCount" -type DWord

            }
            else
            {

                Set-ItemProperty $RegPath "AutoLogonCount" -Value "1" -type DWord

            }
            if($Script)
            {

                Set-ItemProperty $RegROPath "(Default)" -Value "$Script" -type String

            }
            else
            {

                Set-ItemProperty $RegROPath "(Default)" -Value "" -type String

            }        
        }

        catch
        {

            Write-Output "An error had occured $Error"

        }
    }

    End
    {

        #End

    }

}

Set-AutoLogon -DefaultUsername "user" -DefaultDomainName "domain.com" -DefaultPassword "password" -Script "C:\script.bat"

$domain = "domain.com"
$PlainPassword = "password"
$SecurePassword = $PlainPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$user = "user"
$username = "$domain\$user"
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$SecurePassword)
Add-Computer -DomainName $domain -Credential $credential | out-null

Start-Sleep -Seconds 10

restart-computer -force
```

Let me know if you need anymore information
Thanks for any help :D

Comment: PowerShell `v1.0`?  Doesn't 7 SP2 come with `v2.0` by default?

Comment: v1.0 correct. These machines are all running SP1

Comment: Just a side-note, in the name of security, why?

Comment: I'd suggest running under a local account, then explicitly logging in with domain credentials (with a retry if necessary). I can't think of any simple way to do that with PowerShell v1, though (reams of compiled C# don't count). Depending on what the script is doing, you could consider using Group Policy; once the machines are domain joined they're easier to administer remotely.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control over that. Trust me, I understand how bad it is.@TheIncorrigible1

Comment: Windows 7 comes with PowerShell 2.0. The folder path contains "v1.0" but it's still PowerShell v2. Run `$PSVersionTable` at a PowerShell prompt.

Comment: He's on SP 1 which comes with PS 1

Comment: Sorry, but that is not correct. [Windows 7 came with PowerShell 2.0](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/01/07/how-do-i-install-powershell-on-windows-7-and-other-questions/).

Answer (score -1):

Seems network is not ready.

You can try to use group policy named "Always wait for the network at computer startup and logon"